# How to write to HDFS from a Spark Streaming script

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am executing a Spark Streaming application and I want to dump some result to HDFS which is not in form of RDD ,they are simple strings . So how can I dump this data to HDFS , and if there is a way using which we can append these data to a file would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You always can create rdd from array of string:
`val newRDD = sc.parallelize(/* here your list or array */)`

For writing output to file you can use saveAsTextFiles() method. `foreachRDD + saveAsParquet(path, overwrite = true)` - using this you can write each rdd to a single file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I wanted to know if there is way to do without converting it to the RDD.And can the above saveAsParquet method be used for appending to the same file so that there is no overwrite.

Comment: Stream is represented as a sequence of RDDs - so you need to use rdd.

To append data you can use: val data = sc.textFile("/path/to/my/file")
than add new values to data and save as new file